# Inverted Pendulum dynamic eqution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

I'd be glad to have some assistance with following one:

[image]

According to my torque equation, I'm getting following one ($\theta$ is small angle and therefore approximation)

\begin{array}{l}
I = {J_c} + m{\left( {\frac{L}{2}} \right)^2}\\
\sum {\tau  = I\ddot \theta }  = M - {{\vec L}_2} \times {{\vec F}_k} - {{\vec L}_1} \times {{\vec F}_c} + \frac{{\vec L}}{2} \times {{\vec F}_g} = M - {L_2}kx - {L_1}c\dot x + mg\frac{L}{2}\sin \left( \theta  \right) \approx \\
\quad  \approx M - L_2^2k\theta  - L_1^2c\dot \theta  + mg\frac{L}{2}\theta \\
\left( {{J_c} + \frac{{m{L^2}}}{4}} \right)\ddot \theta  + L_2^2k\theta  - mg\frac{L}{2}\theta  + L_1^2c\dot \theta  = M
\end{array}

In next step I was given m,L,c and k (assuming g=9.8) and requested to calculate the required M so that $\theta$ would be with specific value (probably there are some assumptions on $L_1$ and $L_2$.
What about $J_c$ (polar moment of inertia of the pendulum around its center of mass is)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of moment of inertia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia)!

However, I feel you don't need the moment of inertia around the rod center of mass since you are calculating your moments with regard to the bottom end of the rod.

You can find the right moment of inertia on the same page as above of you can calculate it yourself by the [Huygens–Steiner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem).

Please correct me if I'm wrong.